# Yii2 API: как правильно организовать?

Tags: yii2, api, rest

Я разрабатываю api для приложения на React. Как в Yii2 организовать работу api я знаю, все настроил, все работает. Но есть один момент, который хочу сделать и может есть какое то решение, которое я не нашел.

Например, у меня есть api для товаров, новостей и списка партнеров. В приложения есть главная страница, где надо использовать все эти api. Я пробовал сделать 2 варианта:

1. Делается 3 запроса
2. Делается 1 запрос на специальный роут, который отдает сразу 3 api

Но, тут надо сделать, что бы по api еще приходили слайды на главную. Если брать второй вариант, то тогда мне надо дописывать тот роут. Делать 4 запроса - мне кажется это плохая идея.

Есть ли вариант, что бы можно было при одном запросе указать какие api мне нужны?

Answer (score 0):

Лучшего решения здесь нет. В первом варианте вы можете переиспользовать ваш api в разных местах вашего клиента, запрашивая только то, что нужно. Но при этом возникают сетевые издержки. Есть ли проблемы с производительностью? Если нет, берите первый вариант. Как часто меняется информация? Предсказуемо ли меняется? Если информация меняется редко или предсказуемо, то кэшируйте. На клиенте и на сервере.

Есть сторонники обеих вариантов, выбирать вам. Если нет серьезных проблем с производительностью, я бы предпочел выбрать первый вариант (не хотелось бы держать все в одной корзине). Эти варианты не взаимоисключающие, можно добавить и второй вариант.

Так же можно использовать так называемые `batch requests`. Для объединения нескольких запросов в один. Напирмер, у [microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis#example-requests-and-responses).

P.S. Вы вольны делать все что угодно. Не усложняйте себе жизнь. Принципы программирования созданы чтобы ее облегчить(делайте как вам удобно). Решайте задачи, по мере их поступления. Ведь вы делаете api для своего одного клиента (react), а не общедоступное. И вы ведь не делаете сервис для яндекса?). На досуге можете почитать еще про graphql.

Comment: насколько будет "костыльно", если я напишу свой метод, который по определенному роуту будет отдавать только те api, которые я укажу? это будет кощунство?)

Comment: Не совсем понял про `будет отдавать только те api`. Какие те api? У вас вроде как одно api.

Comment: имею ввиду, что я буду делать запрос, в котором буду передавать ?api=news:products:partner

Comment: @Diefair обновил ответ

Comment: о graphql читал, надо будет еще почитать) по поводу "делать как хочу": я пишу часто api и хочется сделать механизм, которым буду пользоваться всегда